# Compare Date with Trigger on Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, database-trigger

I have a table with those columns:

- DateDebVal DATE
- DateFinVal DATE
- isCurrent NUMBER

And I need to have a trigger that do something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_date
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON tablename
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        IF sysdate < DateFinVal
             set isCurrent = 1
        ELSE
             set isCurrent = 0
END;
```

Can I compare those dates? Is it a good idea to use a trigger instead of a view or a procedure?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `DATE` columns (or values) do not have a format. Any format you see when retrieving those values is applied by the SQL tool you are using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I thought it can lead to some errors because it's not always in the same format.

Comment: Again: (real) `DATE` values do **NOT** have  "a format".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name okay, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dates can absolutely be compared, but assignment is done using `:=` in PL/SQL (not with `set`)

If you want to change the value of a newly inserted row, you have to use a `BEFORE` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_date
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON tablename
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF sysdate < :new.datefinval
    :new.iscurrent := 1;
  ELSE
    :new.iscurrent := 0;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Online example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=796347f1b5811448dddf2d0a532c2c2c

Answer (score 0):

Sysdate and DateFinVal are of DATE type so you would compare those. It depends what for you need this trigger.

Comment: I need this trigger to have in the isCurrent column the result if the data is current or not.

Comment: OK but pay attention that sysdate is the date when the insert or update on your table happens.